# error when trying to create import / export in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE DIRECTORY BASED ON AN EXISTING LIBRARY:

CREATE DIRECTORY hr_imp_dir as ‘/u02/oradata/hr_imp_dir/’ ;
```

For example: export 2 `EMPLOYEES` and `DEPARTMENTS` tables using the datapump tool:

```
expdp hr/hr@orcl tables=EMPLOYEES,DEPARTMENTS directory=hr_imp_dir dumpfile =EMP_DEPT.dmp logfile=expEMP_DEPT.log create directory hr_imp_dir as ‘/u02/oradata/hr_imp_dir/’ ;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error ORA-01034 means that the Oracle Service is not available or is not started. Please look at [here](https://www.tekstream.com/resource-center/ora-01034-oracle-not-available/#:%7E:text=An%20ORA-01034%20error%20is,allocated%20for%20your%20Oracle%20database.) or [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=ora-01034-oracle-not-available) for more information.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

1. It appears that you executed the `create directory` command without first logging in to an active instance. You should have used the `connect` command, like `connect username/password@service_name`.
2. `expdp` is an operating system command, not a SQL or SQL*Plus command.

See here:

- [SQL*Plus Quick Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpqr/index.html#SQPQR101)
- [Oracle Data Pump (expdp, impdp) in Oracle Database 10g, 11g, 12c, 18c, 19c](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g)
- [Oracle Data Pump Export](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-data-pump-export-utility.html#GUID-5F7380CE-A619-4042-8D13-1F7DDE429991)